# Creating a JOGL texture from a BufferedImage

Tags: java, 3d, textures, jogl

In previous versions of JOGL, I could create a Texture from a BufferedImage using the following handy function:

```
public static Texture makeTextureFromBufferedImage(BufferedImage b) {
    return TextureIO.newTexture(b,true);
}
```

Now however in the latest JOGL release the TextureIO.newTexture method doesn't seem to accept a BufferedImage any more.

So what is now the recommended way to create a Texture from a BufferedImage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep it short: Use AWTTextureIO instead.